# Longest Prefix between two MySQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, phone-number, cdr

I have a MySQL database with 2 tables:

Table A:

- Number
- Location

Table B:

- Calling Code
- Area Code
- Location

Initially, I have about 60,000 entries in table A, which has the Location column empty at the beginning. In table B I have about 250,000+ entries with a lot of area codes, calling codes (1, 011) and their respective location in the world. What I want is a FAST way of populating the table A's location column with the location of the number.

So for example if the first entry in Table A is (17324765600, null) I want to read trough table B and get the location for that number. Right now I am getting the location of a number with this query:

```
SELECT b.location
FROM 
  tableB b
  LEFT JOIN tableA a
     ON a.number LIKE CONCAT(b.calling_code, b.code, '%')
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(b.code) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

That gives me the proper location (even though I have my doubts that it can fail..). The problem is that performance wise this method is a no go. If I loop over all the 50k number

Update 1

Allow me to put some sample data with the expected output:
Sample Table A:

```
number  location
17324765600 NULL
01134933638950  NULL
0114008203800   NULL
…60k Records + at the moment..
```

Sample Table B:

```
calling_code    code    location
1   7324765 US-NJ
011 34933   Spain
011 400820  China
…250,000+ records at the moment
```

Expected output after the processing:
Table A:

```
number  location
17324765600 US-NJ
01134933638950  Spain
0114008203800   China
```

The best I’ve come up with is the following update statement:

```
UPDATE tableA a JOIN tableB b ON a.location LIKE CONCAT(b.calling_code, b.code, '%') SET a.location = b.location
```

Of course here I am not sure if it will always return the longest prefix of the code, for example if in the above tables there was another code starting with 73247XX let’s say  that code is for Iowa (just as an example).. I am not sure if the query will always return the longest code so here I would also need help.

Let me know if the samples help.

.SQL for the database structure: 
[Download](https://www.sendspace.com/file/3dqj8g)

Update 2:

I am thinking on doing this the following way:

Before inserting the data in table A I am thinking of exporting Table B into a CSV and sort it by area code, that way I can have 2 pointers one for the array of entries for table A and one for the csv, both sorted by area code that way I can make a kind of parallel search and populate the entry's location on PHP and not having to do this in MySQL.

Let me know if this approach seems like a better option if so I will test it out and publish the answer.

Comment: So do I understand that you want to `UPDATE` the column `a.location` with the value of `b.location` you retrieved with this query?  It can be done in one statement.

Comment: I didn't notice the `LIMIT 1` at first. For cases where there are multiple matches requiring the `LIMIT`, can you post what the output would be, with a sample set of input rows and output rows? I suspect you want the longest `b.code` 's corresponding `b.location`, and that may require a subquery join. Please post some real sample rows...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski see above samples and let me know if this clears up. And yes I am looking to get the longest b.code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take the below approach since I did not received any clear response:

Prior to the process I prepared 2 new tables, a table for country codes and a table for state codes (since I also need to know the state in case the number is within the US). Both tables will have: country, state, calling_code, code …

As for these 2 tables I broke down all the numbers with the prefixes and grouped them by area code so instead of having full 6 numbers to identify a country/state I grouped them by the first 3 numbers and if the code is within the USA or not, hence the 2 tables.

With this modifications I was able to break the 250,000 + rows table to only about 300 rows (each table).

After this I will follow these steps:

1. I get the list of phone numbers
2. I first execute a query very similar as the one I posted to update all the numbers that belong to the country_code table
3. I then update the rows that are still without location assigned with the table of state_code
4. I had to put some kind of cron in order to get this done every x amount of time to avoid having a huge amount of phones.

This may not be the best approach but for the 50k numbers that are in place at the moment I was able to (manually executing query by query with some more polishing) get it down to about 10 seconds, executing this every x amount of time (which will allow performing this process to less than 10k numbers) will make this smoothly.

I will mark this as the answer but if someone else magically comes up with a better answer I will make sure to update this.

Divide and conquer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want all locations, then you need to remove **LIMIT**

```
SELECT b.location
FROM 
  tableB b
  LEFT JOIN tableA a
     ON a.number LIKE CONCAT(b.calling_code, b.code, '%')
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(b.code);
```

If you want the **same location name should not come twice** then you need to use **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT b.location
FROM 
  tableB b
  LEFT JOIN tableA a
     ON a.number LIKE CONCAT(b.calling_code, b.code, '%')
GROUP BY b.location  ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(b.code) ;
```

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by getting all the locations or not showing the location twice.. please see above samples and let me know if your answer still applies.

Answer (score 0):

You have one join only with 250000 records, its not so stressful. You should take proper indexing for search columns and `fine tune your mysql server`. A `good indexing & server variables well` to set will solve your problem easily. Optimize your query well.Generally it creates problems when we have much of joins & many string comparison.

I think you need the query like this-

```
UPDATE a SET a.location = ( 
                            SELECT location from b 
                            WHERE a.number LIKE CONCAT(b.calling_code, b.area_code, '%') 
                            ORDER BY LENGTH(CONCAT(b.calling_code, b.area_code, '%')) desc 
                            limit 1
                          );
```

Comment: I am using indexes in pretty much all the columns since in this case there are only 3 in one table and 2 in another which I am using all fields.. would you mind putting up a sample of the approach you would take on this? I have updated the question with some samples

Comment: @BenjaminVison your update query is looking good,  i would create index on a.location and (b.calling_code, b.code).

Comment: yes they both are indexes and still the query just doesn't complete

Comment: @BenjaminVison tell me what you want, longest match & update all recordd of table A

Comment: yes, I would like to find the longest match (the longest tableb.calling_code+code for the tablea.number). And update the table A with the location found of the longest match.

Comment: thanks but it's still really slow, I had to stop the query

Comment: @BenjaminVison  i have use order by length now. use this query , if slow then You can try cursor for that

Comment: @BenjaminVison post outuput i am waiting

Comment: Still not working, I've added a sample of the .sql structure in case you want to fill it up with dummy data and make tests